# Activate the StackExchange new tag warning on ELU

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

In this [meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233897/338924) is a neat functionality to stop people from creating new tags is described. Unfortunately it's not active on ELU. Fortunatly, Laurel has this brought to ELU attention over [here in an answer.](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9481/184706)

> This feature is currently enabled on Stack Overflow, Server Fault, Super User, Unix & Linux, Mi Yodeya, Ask Ubuntu, Physics, Sound Design, Pets, and Mathematics.

It would provide us with this neat warning:

[image]

Since it is already available on other network sites it should be relatively easy to activate it on ELU. I think it would be a great addition and keep senseless tags from being inadvertently created.

Comment: Yeah, why isn't that a default everywhere?

Comment: Don't know about everywhere, but for here, yes please.

Comment: @Mitch maybe the reasoning is that on new sites there are more occasions where you actually want to create tags, as the taxonomy is not as mature yet.

Comment: @Helmar But it doesn't _stop_ the tag from being made, and a question worded like that is not much of a psychological barrier (in my estimation).

Comment: Now I want a [noot-noot] tag....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Done.

Note, this isn't turned on for meta as new tags are far more likely to be needed here (in conjunction with the required tags) as things evolve on the site.

But, it's now enabled on the main site.